# Using parameters from an output

Tags: r, output

I have this code

```
out <- bugs(data, inits=inits,...)
```

and some part of its output is

```
            mean    sd  2.5%    25%    50%
 beta1    0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0
 beta2    0.1   0.0   0.0    0.1    0.1
```

I was wondering how I could use the betas. For example how could I calculate beta1*10. I tried `10*out$beta1`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `bugs()` produces list of lists. Estimated mean values of parameters are in sublist called `mean`. You can check whole structure of output by function `str(out)`.

```
out$mean$beta1
out$mean$beta2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was after. It perfectly works :)